# How to transform array to objects in mongodb/mongoose aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

There are three collections.

**Leave**

- _id
- user (ref to user model)
- status

**LeaveApproval**

- _id
- leave (ref to leave model)
- auditUser (ref to user model)
- role

**User**

- _id
- name

After performing lookup stage on Leave collection:

```
Leave.aggregate([
    $lookup: {
        from: 'leaveapprovals',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'leave',
        as: 'approverRecommender'
    }
])
```

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('6262851ab059b81fd9076532'),
    user: ObjectId('21ca9490192add08fa385aec'),
    status: "pending",
    approverRecommender: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId('6262851ab059b81fd907653d'),
            leave: ObjectId('6262851ab059b81fd9076532'),
            auditUser: ObjectId('61ca9490192add08fa385aeb'),
            role: "recommender"    
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId('6262851ab059b81fd907653d'),
            leave: ObjectId('6262851ab059b81fd9076532'),
            auditUser: ObjectId('71ca9490192add08fa385aec'),
            role: "approver"    
        }
    ]
}
```

The result that I want to get is:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('6262851ab059b81fd9076532'),
    user: ObjectId('21ca9490192add08fa385aec'),
    status: "pending",
    recommender: {
        _id: ObjectId('61ca9490192add08fa385aeb'),
        name: "Andrew"
    },
    approver: {
        _id: ObjectId('71ca9490192add08fa385aec'),
        name: "James"
    }
}
```

How can I transform it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$lookup` - Need a nested `$lookup`. First `$lookup` with pipeline to join `leave` and `leaveapprovals` collection. While inner  `$lookup` to join `user` collection and return `auditUser` and `role` fields.
2. `$set` -

   2.1. For `approver` field, filter `approverRecommender` array field for the `approver` role and take the first document via `$first.`

   2.2. For `recommender` field, filter `approverRecommender` array field for the `recommender` role and take the first document via `$first.`
3. `$project` - Decorate the output document. Use `$first` to return the first document for `approver` and `recommender` as from Result 2 both fields return as array.

```
db.leave.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "leaveapprovals",
      let: {
        leaveId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$leaveId",
                "$leave"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "user",
            localField: "auditUser",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "auditUser"
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            auditUser: 1,
            role: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "approverRecommender"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      approver: {
        "$first": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$approverRecommender",
            "cond": {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.role",
                "approver"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      recommender: {
        "$first": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$approverRecommender",
            "cond": {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.role",
                "recommender"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      approver: {
        "$first": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$approverRecommender",
            "cond": {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.role",
                "approver"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      recommender: {
        "$first": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$approverRecommender",
            "cond": {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.role",
                "recommender"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      user: 1,
      status: 1,
      "approver": {
        $first: "$approver.auditUser"
      },
      "recommender": {
        $first: "$recommender.auditUser"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zu1p4Dr_CxS)